# Case Statement with multiple conditions using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

**SELECT case when status = 'A' and login='Y'
    then 'Login Allowed' else 'Enable the Login Status' end as UserLoginStatus 
FROM Users.**

i have verified few answers from stackoverflow but unable find the code to handle the above case.

Below sample code will work for single conditions(case when with status='A') .

```
**CriteriaBuilder cbr = session_hiber.getCriteriaBuilder();
cbr.selectCase()
.when(cbr.equal(path.get("status"), "A"), "Login Allowed")
.otherwise("Enable the Login Status")
.alias("UserLoginStatus");**
```

How to handle the Case criteria with multiple conditions using criteriaBuilder.

Comment: have you read the documentation?

Comment: i read the documentation and not able find the solution.could you please help.

Can i add another and condition same like sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

came across this post while I was working on same scenario.

Following code worked for me. by creating the list of predicates and then passing it in the when clause

```
List<Predicate> casePredicates = getcasePredicate(criteriaBuilder,contractBidRoot);
criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                    .when(criteriaBuilder.and(casePredicates.toArray(new
                    Predicate[casePredicates.size()])), "DISCARD")
                    .otherwise(contractBidRoot.get(Constant.STATUS))));
```

```
public List<Predicate> getcasePredicate(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<ContractBid> contractBidRoot)
{
       List<Predicate> casePredicates = new ArrayList<>(); 
       casePredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(contractBidRoot.get("date"),
       LocalDateTime.now()));
       casePredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(contractBidRoot.get("status"), "DONE"));
       return casePredicates;
}
```